# Discord: Gives an error in the console related to my id

Tags: python

I'm writing a discord bot.
Today I checked the function and it worked, the function is responsible for the warns on the server, I tested the function on myself, but the bot cannot block me on the server and started working incorrectly
I started to give an error in the console, my id is in the console.
I decided to re-create the json file, made adjustments in it, added `{}` so that it would write all the information about the warns in them, but after running it, the json file was cleared and was empty
I am attaching the error and code below.

Error in console:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\mybot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in 
_run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\mybot\bot\botrun.py", line 58, in on_message
data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] += 1
KeyError: '274498213417844746'
```

code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  await bot.process_commands(message)                                                                                                                     
  WARN = BADWORDS + LINKS

  for i in  range(0, len(WARN)):
   if WARN[i] in message.content.lower():
     with open('users.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        file.close()

     with open('users.json', 'w') as file:
        data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] += 1  #Says there is an error on this line
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

        file.close()
```

The json file is empty, because everything is deleted from there

What could be the problem?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if the key exists in the dictionary.

```
if str(message.author.id) not in data:
    # If the key is not in the dict, add it and make it an empty dict
    data[str(message.author.id)] = {}
    # Set warns to 1
    data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] = 1
else:
    # Increment warns by 1
    data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] += 1
```

Also, no need to close file if you use with syntax.

Comment: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Throws an error in the console and still clears the json even though I don't close it
It gives one warning and stops working

Comment: @Nuestr1k That is something else (reading a blank file). Try to debug it line by line, but I think the code should work, it could be the constant reading and writing of the file (could try to add an `os.fsync()` after writing the file, but could also not read and write so often). If it turns out to be the constant rw I would suggest rewriting to first load the dict from file, then loop through and add what needs to be added to the dict, and just then write to the file. If there are multiple services accessing the file concurrently I would suggest to use a database.